# null comparison

Tags: java

This might sound like a real dumb question but please bear with me :)
so I have a if condition in my code like `if ((msgBO.getEmpId().equals("") == false )) {
// do something
}` My question is, if I make the above statement as `msgBO.getEmpId().equals(null) == false` 
would it make any difference or this way I am trying to compare two different things?

Comment: I'm guessing getEmpId() returns a String?

Comment: Hi James, yes it returns a String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a big difference between `""` (the empty String) and `null` (no String at all).

Any Object reference can point to `null`.  That represents 'no data' or 'nothing.'  The empty string `""` represents a String with no length.

An example of this is the following:

```
String one = null;
String two = "";
int oneLength = one.length();
int twoLength = two.length();
```

The first call to `length` will throw a `NullPointerException`.  And the second will return `0`.

Comment: Justin so in my case, I can simply do,if mgbBO.getEmpId() == null. Right?

Answer (score 2):

These are different things. In particular, the test

```
msgBO.getEmpId.equals(null) == false
```

a.k.a.

```
!msgBO.getEmpId.equals(null)
```

is guaranteed to always succeed (at least, if the `equals` method involved is written according to the standard set of rules), since no object is ever allowed to compare equal to `null`:

> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

([Documentation of equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29))

So, in other word, if you already know, that `msgBO.getEmpId != null`, then you also know the outcome of the call to `equals`. And unless you know that `msgBO.getEmpId != null`, calling `equals` is a `NullPointerException` waiting to happen. So, one often sees:

```
msgBO.getEmpId != null && msgBO.getEmpId.equals("...stuff...")
```

or even

```
"...stuff...".equals(msgBO.getEmpId)
```

Comment: >>since no object is ever allowed to compare equal to null... tell that to the json guys :)... and technically speaking you can have equals(Object) return true; you can do weird things w/ arbitrary improper impl. of hashCode/equals

Answer (score 0):

`""` (an empty string) and `null` are not the same.  `.equals(null)` on a `String` will never return true.

Answer (score 0):

A `null` reference and String of length 0 are two completely different things in Java. Two other points:

- `getEmpId` is either a getter method missing the braces for method invocation or a public field, which is generally frowned upon (and badly named in this case).
- if `getEmpId` is/returns `null`, teh calling `equals()` on it will caus a `NullPointerException` - which is why you should reverse the comparison when comparing with literal strings: `if("foo".equals(variable))`
- Comparing a boolean expression explicitly using `==` is ugly. Instead you can use negation: `if(!msgBO.getEmpId.equals(""))` or `if(!msgBO.getEmpId != null)`

Comment: Hey Micheal, getEmpId is a getter. getEmpId(). Sorry for the typo. and thanks for pointing out the better coding practices.

Answer (score 0):

They are different , what you want is

```
msgBO.getEmpId == null
```

for the other case

Comment: Hi Learning, I guess you are right, I need to simply check for null instead of empty String

Answer (score 0):

It does make a difference.

`msgBO.getEmpId.equals("")` compares `msgBO.getEmpId` with an empty `String`

`msgBO.getEmpId.equals(null)` compares `msgBO.getEmpId` with a `null` value. This is wrong because it will throw `NullPointerException` if `msgBO.getEmpId` is `null`. If you want to check if the value is null you should use such a condition instead: `msgBO.getEmpId == null`.

What is correct in this situation depends on the type of a value returned by `msgBO.getEmpId`. If it isn't `String` then only comparing with `null` makes sense. If it is `String` both values may have sense and then it depends how you represent an empty value of `msgBO.getEmpId`. In this case if you use `null` for an empty value you should compare with `null` and if you use `""` for an empty value you should compare with `""`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare two different things.  It might still work, but one is checking for an empty string and one is checking if the variable is null.

Also a faster check to see if the string is empty is just to check

```
if (string.length == 0).
```

(You will get an exception, however, if the string is null so don't do this if null checking, unless you want to handle the null case with the caught exception).